# d3.selectAll enter exit of nested key value pairs -- aka: how do array selections work?

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I have a nested array of data that I am using to create a grouped bar chart. I am having trouble assigning a key to the datajoin of the nested array.

Below is the input data, the working datajoin for the top level, and two partial implementations of what I am trying to accomplish. I am so close!

```
// input data    

var data = [
      {"key":"cat1","value":[{"key":"subcatA","value":100},{"key":"subcatB","value":200}]},
      {"key":"cat2","value":[{"key":"subcatA","value":150},{"key":"subcatB","value":250}]}
    ];
```

To access the **top level** and build the main categories, I do this:

```
// top level (all good)
var plot = d3.select('#plot');

plot.selectAll(".category")
    .data(data,function(d) {return d.key;}) // <-- return key on datajoin
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "category")
```

*Returning `d.key` on the datajoin keeps track of each category such that enter() and exit() is not a giant mess of animation. See Mike Bostock's [General Update Pattern, II](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221) for reference on adding a key to a datajoin.*

To plot the **second level**, I do this:

```
// second level (plots but no key is assigned)

plot.selectAll(".category").selectAll(".bar")
    .data(function (d) {return d.value; }) // <-- is this right?
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar")
```

There is no key assigned so d3 handles updates rather randomly. I can get what I want for only the first iteration if I do this:

```
 // second level (key is assigned but first iteration only)

 plot.selectAll(".g-category").selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data[0].value, function (d) {return d.key; }) // <-- first category only
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar")
```

Perfection except I need to iterate over `data`, not just `data[0]`. My problem is as soon as I try, I get into a conflict of interest with `d3.selectAll` and make a general mess of things.

The answer to this question may be simple, but I am missing it: How do I go about properly selecting and assigning keys to nested arrays in d3?

Comment: Before anyone trying to answer your question: `d3.selectAll(".category").data(//etc...` is **not** the correct way to create an enter selection. It should be `selection.selectAll`. Is your code correct?

Comment: I hot swapped d3 in the question, and have since edited the code, thanks.

Comment: It's better now with `plot.selectAll(etc...`, thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data method in your second level has just one argument:

```
.data(function (d) {
    return d.value; 
});
```

For assigning the key function you have to pass a second argument. For instance:

```
.data(function(d) {
    return d.value
}, function(d) {
    return d.key
});
```

You can better see it in one line:

```
.data(function(d) { return d.value }, function(d) { return d.key });
//2nd arg after the comma ----------^
```

However, to facilitate human reading, I'd advise you to use different property names for level 1 and level 2. Right now everything is `value` and `key`, which can be hard to understand (not for the machine, though). For instance, in the above snippet, `value` refers to the first level array, while `key` refers to the second level array, not the first one... do you see the mess?

Here is a demo with your data:

```js
var data = [{
    "key": "cat1",
    "value": [{
      "key": "subcatA",
      "value": 100
    }, {
      "key": "subcatB",
      "value": 200
    }]
  },
  {
    "key": "cat2",
    "value": [{
      "key": "subcatA",
      "value": 150
    }, {
      "key": "subcatB",
      "value": 250
    }]
  }
];

var body = d3.select("body");
var outer = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(data, function(d) {
    return d.key
  })
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "outer");

var inner = outer.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.value
  }, function(d) {
    console.log("the key is: " + d.key)
    return d.key
  })
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.key + " - " + d.value
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```